# Button style depending on Window.IsActive

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-3.5

I need to have a button change its style depending on the `Window.IsActive` property - the foreground color should change when the window looses its focus.

The following code won`t result in any changes:

```
<Style TargetType="Button"
       x:Key="SYS_Window_Button">
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{StaticResource SYS_Window_Button_Text}" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      Margin="0" />
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=IsActive}"
                                 Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="Red" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: i tried it and it is working fine ..how are you applying this style to your button?. I tried with static values instead of resources for foreground... can you try putting the static color value instead of StaticResource...in <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{StaticResource SYS_Window_Button_Text}" />.

Comment: Is the foreground changing when the window loses focus? I cant`t get it to work, even by using static color values instead of resources.

Comment: yes.. it is changing.. when my window is not active

Comment: Hum - should have checked this earlier... The code would be working fine, if the Button would have had a text content. The button only contains a Path / Geometry. Thank you nit...